# How do add a Fade in and Fade out effect to a text slide using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, gallery

How do you add a Fade in and Fade out effect to a text slide using jquery

I would like to have each quote fade in and out versus just disappear and reappearing sluggishly.

```
   <head>
    <script>
    var counter = 0;

    function changeText()
    {
    var quotes = new Array();

    quotes[0] = "quote1";
    quotes[1] = "quote2";
    quotes[2] = "quote3";
    quotes[3] = "quote4";
    quotes[4] = "quote5";

    if (counter > 4)
        {
        counter = 0;
        }

    document.getElementById("textslide").innerHTML = quotes[counter];

    setTimeout(function(){changeText()},10000);
    counter ++;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="changeText();">
    <p id="textslide"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't show any attempt to use jQuery. Any answer would require far too much explanation of the library, where to use it, and how to apply it to this scenario. Essentially it would require an entire reworking of this snippet. Perhaps you should start by visiting their site and reading up on it, or examining the source code of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery's [fadein()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeout()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) effectively like

```
$( "#DivID" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    //  After Animation complete
  });
```